# CaptureElement was not found , missing assembly reference

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express, developing new camera app for windows mobile 8.1 , getting error :

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="myCaptureElement" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"         
                Width="320" Height="240" />
```

> CaptureElement was not found, missing assembly reference . .

Comment: Are you targetting WP8.1 Silverlight or Runtime? The [CaptureElement class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement) is only for Runtime.

Comment: ya i am targetting for wp8.1 silverlight . thnks for quick reply , i have also 1 prob which claas have to use for capturing photo and adding diiferent resolution and many more option , not getting good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you are targeting WP8.1 Silverlight - and as [MSDN says, CaptureElement class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement) is olny for Runtime:

> Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]

If you need to take a photo in Silverlight, you may think of using [Camera Capture Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which:

> Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 | Windows Phone OS 7.1

You may also have a look at this [nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx).

Comment: thnks , i have used camera capture task , how can i add more option like resolution & any more option  to by default photo settings option

Comment: @user3698351 Try to follow some blogs, tutorials, MSDN - there are many of them if you try via google/bing. Then if you still have some problems - ask another question on SO.

Comment: ok , i have tried almost msdn and other blogs for camera capture task but they have not given further to add additional options. thnks for quick reply i will post another quetion